# WCF-Service event issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, events

i've got the problem , that i don't know how to forward an object ( received via WCF ) to another thread ( for example a WinForm ).

I create the service in the class **ComManager.cs**:

```
        var wcfServer = new ServiceHost(typeof(ClientListenerService));
        wcfServer.Open();
```

I have a service interface implementation like this in **ClientListenerService.cs**:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single ..... )]
public class ClientListenerService : IClient
{
    // This is a theoretical approach, as there is no way to forward an event handler to the service here
    public event xyz;

    public void AlarmTriggered(AlarmTriggeredDto dto)
    {
        // How do i get the object to some kind of event handler outside of this service here???
        // I need sth. like: 
        xyz.Invoke(dto);
    }
}
```

When the method **AlarmTriggered(dto)** is called, i need to forward the object to another thread.
I have no clue how to achieve this, as i can't find a way to pass any parameters to the servicehost ( like an eventhandler or sth. ) that my ClientListenerService can use afterwards.
All the workarounds with static objects/queues don't fit in my requirement.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To further explain what John is saying, when your WCF service is configured to be a Singleton (`[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]`), you can create and configure the instance to be used as the singleton beforehand and pass that into your ServiceHost constructor.

```
ClientListenerService svc = new ClientListenerService();
svc.xyz += myListener.xyzHandler;
var wcfServer = new ServiceHost(svc, baseAddresses);
wcfServer.Open();
```

I'd also recommend [downloading the ServiceModelEx library from iDesign](http://idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=-1&tabid=19&download=262), which provides `ServiceHost<T>` (written by Juval Lowy, author of *Programming WCF Services*) I've found it much easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I was trying stuff with this singleton instance thing, but i didn't know that it has to be constructed like this!

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be constructed that way, but it allows you to, since a singleton is a special situation. By default, WCF will use the default constructor on your class.

Comment: The link to the ServicemodelEx download link appears to be broken. It is at http://idesign.net/Downloads/GetDownload/1887

Answer (score 0):

Your ClientListenerService is a class just like any other. It can have a public event, just like any other. The other code in your host can subscribe to that event, just like normal.

Comment: No, the class is instantiiated by the "ServiceHost" class and i have no way get anything thorugh to this instances...

Comment: Use [`ServiceHost constructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585487.aspx)